# Some questions in a paper by E. H. Neville (1949) about Farey series?

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, sequences-and-series, elementary-proofs

I am reading the paper

[MR0029924](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0029924): Neville, E. H. The structure of Farey series. Proc. London Math. Soc. (2) 51, (1949). 132–144. (Reviewer: W. H. Simons)

and by now two questions raised for me;

1. for the proof of Theorem 1, it says that:

"This theorem is an immediate corollary of the pair of inequalities..."
but it takes almost one page for me to prove it. Is there more simple way that I missed it.

2. It seems Theorem 3 instead of

"...difference $|vx—uy|$ has the value 1 if and only if ..."

must be

"...difference $|vx—uy|$ has the value greater than 1 if and only if ..."

Is there any comments? thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2: no, the theorem is about attaining the unit bound.

Comment: 1: multiply the first inequality by $c$, the second by $a$ and add them.